# JQuery selector can't find id

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome extension.

When I add click event statements, JQuery doesn't seem to operate if I try to select an element id via selector.

For ex:

**This doesn't work:**

```
$("#someId").click(function(){
    console.log("blah");
});
```

**This works:**

```
$("*").click(function(){
    console.log("blah");
});
```

What can cause element selection by id to be unreachable for me?

Comment: is the element added dynamically ie using another script after the page is loaded and the handler is registered

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){});`?

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Is there a way to defer handler registration? I've put the event inside of $(document).ready(function(...){}); - but no luck.

Comment: @putvande: I tried adding the handler inside of it but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, I assume the element is added dynamically

You need to use event delegation

```
$(document).on('click', "#someId", function(){
    console.log("blah");
});
```

Comment: That's the answer, appreciated! Just found out that it is a newer version of "live". For those who use 1.6-: use "live" instead of "on". (Using newer version is wiser though)